# Expectation of a sum of (a random number of) random variables.

Tags: probability-theory

I'm wondering if the following bound is true:
$$E[X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_N]\leq E[N]\cdot E[\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_N\}]$$
The variables $N,X_1,\ldots,X_N$ are not independent.
It seems right, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Edit: Kurt G. pointed out how this is not generally true. An additional assumption I did not mention is the fact that $N$ does not affect the total sum. More specifically, for any two possible values $\alpha, \beta $ of $N$, it is true that $E[X_1+\cdots+X_N | N=\alpha] = E[X_1+\cdots+X_N|N=\beta]$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\max$ using `\max`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: Thanks for comment @joriki, this is the first time I'm making a post.

Comment: Do you intend to assume that the $X_j$ take nonnegative values only?

Comment: @GregMartin Yes. More specifically $\forall i, X_i \in \{1,2,..,c\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is generally false:

Let $X_i$ be $X$ for all $i$ where $X=1+P$ and
$P$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda=1\,.$
Then $X$ takes values in $\mathbb N$ with  mean two and variance one and
$$
X_1+X_2+\dots+X_N=N\,X=N\,\max(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_N)\,.
$$
Setting $N=X$ gives
$$
\mathbb E[N\,X]=\operatorname{Cov}[N,X]+\mathbb E[N]\mathbb E[X]=\operatorname{Var}[X]+4=5\,.
$$
The LHS of your inequality is therefore five. The RHS however is
$$
\mathbb E[N]\mathbb E[X]=4\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to think more about my application to see if it applies.